# Styling data row of the dynamic datatable

Tags: php, css, datatables

Currently I have been building my tables manually and here are my sample codes.

```
echo"<tr>";
  echo"<td style='width: 10%;word-wrap: break-word;'>$count</td>";
  echo"<td style='width: 25%;word-wrap: break-word;' class='center'>{$uName}</td>";
  echo"<td style='width: 25%;word-wrap: break-word;' class='center'>{$ufName}</td>";
echo"</tr>";
```

Now, I have moved into **datatables** and do the calling as below.

```
$('#activeUserGrid').dataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 2 ] }],
    "aoColumns": [ { sClass: "alignRight" }  ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "getUser.php" 
    });
```

The problem now I want to style each row like e.g.

```
width: 25%;word-wrap: break-word;
```

Where to assign this style?

Comment: In an external CSS file, please :-)

Comment: I mean how to call the external file here? I dont get you ? Because I need to control each invididual column ?

Comment: You call an external style sheet in the `<head>` element of your HTML document. Cf. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_href.asp

Comment: I know how to call but how to relate that particular css style to each table? If you notice I have done this sClass: "alignRight"  and this <style media="all" type="text/css">
    .alignRight { text-align: left; }
</style> it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need the attribute `className` of `columnDefs`. Also `targets` to specify columns to apply a class. Something like this:

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { className: "my-class-1", "targets": [ 0, 1 ] }
    { className: "my-class-2", "targets": [ 2, 3 ] }
  ]
});
```

This example is valid for new **1.10 notation**. For legacy (pre 1.10) `className` = `sClass`, `target` = `aTarget`

More details: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Comment: I have set this my css td.right {
text-align: left;
word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
} and I have this for the dataTable "columnDefs": [{ className: "right", "targets": [ 0,1,2,3,4 ] }],  but I dont see the effect of the class what could have been wrong?

Comment: In the Dev Tools of your browser check, maybe something is overriding styles.

Comment: hi I am not sure what I did I put the .table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  word-wrap: break-word;
} in my main .css then it works. I dont know why it does not work via datatable method?